# char variable and if statement error C++

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I have the following `for loop`:

```
string temp;
int responseInt[10][10] = { {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

for (int i = 0; i < numberPros; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numberRes; j++)
    {
        cout << "Is " << process[i] << " holding (h), requesting (r), or doing nothing (n) to " << resources[j] << " ?: ";
        cin >> temp;
        if (temp == 'n')
            responseInt[i][j] = 0;
        else if (temp == 'h')
            responseInt[i][j] == -1;
        else if (temp == 'r')
            responseInt[i][j] == 1;
    }
}
```

However, it's like if the `if` statements are ignored, since the default values for `responseInt`are never changed, even if I type `h` or `r` or `n`.

I already tried with strings, but the same thing happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `temp` is a `string`, but `'n'`, `'h'`, and `'r'` are `char`s. You need to compare like to like.

Comment: `==` and `=` aren't the same thing.  You never assign anything but `0` to the elements of `responseInt`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek now I feel dumb. Half an hour looking at my code, specifically the `if` statements,  and I didn't notice that. Thank you, that fixed my problem!

Comment: For sure the `if` statements are ignored. You won't even be able to run the program because `if (temp == 'n')` won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    string temp;
    int responseInt[10][10] = { {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

    int numberPros = 2;
    int numberRes  = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberPros; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numberRes; j++)
        {
            cout << "Is " << i << " holding (h), requesting (r), or doing nothing (n) to " << j << " ?: ";
            cin >> temp;
            if (temp == "n")
                responseInt[i][j] = 0;
            else if (temp == "h")
                responseInt[i][j] == -1;
            else if (temp == "r")
                responseInt[i][j] == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Your `cin>>temp` is reading a string, so it is best to compare it against strings by using double quotes (e.g. `"r"`) rather than single quotes (e.g. `'r'`).

Note that I've had to include a bunch of extra code to make things compile. This should have been in your question, as a minimum working example (MWE).